# No OpenVPN option in new connection dialogue

Tags: unity, network-manager, openvpn

I am having an issue in 15.04 with NetworkManager vpn connections.  I have openvpn installed, but it does not show up in Unity as an available connection type.

```
john@john-desktop:~$ lsb_release -drc
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
john@john-desktop:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep network-manager
network-manager                     install
network-manager-gnome               install
network-manager-openvpn             install
network-manager-openvpn-gnome       install
network-manager-pptp                install
network-manager-pptp-gnome          install
john@john-desktop:~$
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to use OpenVPN itself to setup your connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an elegant solution, but `sudo apt-get purge`ing and re-installing `network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome openvpn` did the trick.